# PowerShell - Grabbing user from security.etvx files

Tags: powershell, get-winevent, get-eventlog

I'm not use to using PowerShell at all but so far I have the following code to grab a 4625 event

```
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashtable @{Path="C:\Users\ScriptTesting\Desktop\Security.evtx";ProviderName="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing";Id=4625} | Format-List -Property *
```

which gives me the output of

```
Message              : An account failed to log on.
                       
                       Subject:
                        Security ID:        x
                        Account Name:       x
                        Account Domain:     x
                        Logon ID:       0x3E7
                       
                       Logon Type:          2
                       
                       Account For Which Logon Failed:
                        Security ID:        x
                        Account Name:       ScriptTesting
                        Account Domain:     x
                       
                       Failure Information:
                        Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
                        Status:         0xC000006D
                        Sub Status:     0xC000006A
                       
                       Process Information:
                        Caller Process ID:  0x21c
                        Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
                       
                       Network Information:
                        Workstation Name:   x
                        Source Network Address: 127.0.0.1
                        Source Port:        0
                       
                       Detailed Authentication Information:
                        Logon Process:      User32 
                        Authentication Package: Negotiate
                        Transited Services: -
                        Package Name (NTLM only):   -
                        Key Length:     0
                       
                       This event is generated when a logon request fails. It is generated on the computer where access was 
                       attempted.
                       
                       The Subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most 
                       commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or 
                       Services.exe.
                       
                       The Logon Type field indicates the kind of logon that was requested. The most common types are 2 
                       (interactive) and 3 (network).
                       
                       The Process Information fields indicate which account and process on the system requested the logon.
                       
                       The Network Information fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is 
                       not always available and may be left blank in some cases.
                       
                       The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
                        - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
                        - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
                        - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key 
                       was requested.
Id                   : 4625
Version              : 0
Qualifiers           : 
Level                : 0
Task                 : 12544
Opcode               : 0
Keywords             : -9218868437227405312
RecordId             : 24320
ProviderName         : Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
ProviderId           : x
LogName              : Security
ProcessId            : 544
ThreadId             : 6744
MachineName          : x
UserId               : 
TimeCreated          : 3/4/2022 2:24:13 PM
ActivityId           : x
RelatedActivityId    : 
ContainerLog         : c:\users\scripttesting\desktop\security.evtx
MatchedQueryIds      : {}
Bookmark             : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventBookmark
LevelDisplayName     : Information
OpcodeDisplayName    : Info
TaskDisplayName      : Logon
KeywordsDisplayNames : {Audit Failure}
Properties           : {System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty, System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty, 
                       System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty, 
                       System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty...}
```

My issue is I need the "ScriptTesting" from account name contained within the message part. I got

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -Newest 10 | Select @{Name="UserName";Expression={ $_.ReplacementStrings[1] }}
```

to grab the account name, but I cant seem to use a file for Get-EventLog, so what's the easiest way to grab that account name while stating a filepath to the evtx file? (I need to be able to pull it from the evtx file and not live from a machine due to a separate process.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work, though, there is probably a better way to do it. I added a `TimeCreated` property so at least you have some reference.

```
$events = Get-WinEvent "C:\Users\ScriptTesting\Desktop\Security.evtx"
foreach($event in $events) {
    if($event.Id -ne 4625) { continue }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TimeCreated = $event.TimeCreated
        TargetUser  = $event.Properties[5].Value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks just adding the ```$event.Properties[5].Value``` worked for me! But I was wondering if you could explain like I was 5 how that Properties[5].Value works in this case

Comment: @tjw well it's just that all events have the `Properties` property which is just a list of values used to construct the `Message` of the event in addition to other values. When you want to get something from the message of an event go to this property and try to see in what __Index__ it is and for the same events it will always be on that index.